# Connect database from another website

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website in a server A and B, I'm trying to connect the website A to the database allocated in B. I have configured well I think, like:

```
$my-Server = "IP_B";
$my-username = "user_B";
$my-Password = "pass_B";
$my-Database = "database-name_B";
```

I'm getting this error: "Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_B' (4)"
Please, does any one know what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Is your database configured to  listenen on externa ip address? Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: I added the Ip of the server A in Remote Database Access Hosts in server B, I guess that's all?. It is an object-relational DBMS.

Comment: Which? MySql, Oracle ... ?

Comment: It is MySQL...............

Comment: Then look if the `bind-address` in the mysql.ini is set to the external ip-address

Comment: Also check port (default 3306) is opened from server A to server B

Comment: Where can I find mysql.ini using CPanel? and where can I check the ports on my servers?, \

Comment: I hope those aren't the actual variable names... PHP doesn't allow dashes.

Comment: Does server B have a firewall in front of it?